# Selecting a writing system

Tags: qt, fonts, qt4

Is there a way to select a certain writing system (documentation [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/internationalization.html#languages-and-writing-systems) and [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfontdatabase.html#WritingSystem-enum)) to be used in a QTextDocument?

I'm using QTextDocument together with QGraphicsTextItem to show a formatted text in a QGraphicsView. I want to be able to select the writing system for each of the texts, independently of each other.